# How to install GDAL on Google Colab fast?

Tags: python, makefile, google-colaboratory, gdal, yum

I can install GDAL in [Google Colab](http://colab.research.google.com) by running the cell:

```
%%shell
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
sudo yum -y install make automake gcc gcc-c++ libcurl-devel proj-devel geos-devel
cd /tmp
curl -L http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.0.0/gdal-2.0.0.tar.gz | tar zxf -
cd gdal-2.0.0/
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --without-python
make -j4
sudo make install
cd /usr/local
tar zcvf ~/gdal-2.0.0-amz1.tar.gz *
```

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44907360/8565438) answer.

However, it takes way more than half an hour for this cell to complete.

**How could I install `gdal` faster?**

My aim is to run the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47726183/8565438). I have managed to do it, but after a  Colab kernel restart, I have to wait again for the above cell to run.

Comment: Using conda could be faster. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330876/install-conda-package-to-google-colab -- replace ujson with gdal.

Comment: I am happy for you to write a detailed answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [install conda package to google colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59330876/install-conda-package-to-google-colab), this works:

```
%%shell
wget -c https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
chmod +x Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash ./Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local
conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local python=3.6 gdal
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the GDAL command-line tools, you should be able to do this:

```bash
!apt install gdal-bin

!gdalinfo --version
```

Output:

```
GDAL 3.4.3, released 2022/04/22
```

On the other hand, if you're looking to use the GDAL Python bindings, you just need to import the package:

```py
from osgeo import gdal
```

You can also use GDAL via rasterio if you're so inclined:

https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/switch.html

Comment: I think this is the best answer to the question. You can also do `!apt list --installed | grep gdal` and `!dpkg -L gdal-bin | grep /bin/` to see more about what is installed.

Answer (score 1):

GDAL is already pre-installed in Google Colab, so you only have to import it when starting a notebook

```
import gdal
!gdalinfo --version
```

> GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20

It's not the most recent version of GDAL though, but for your sample code it should be sufficient.

By the way, for a full list of pre-installed python libraries in Google Colab, run:

```
!pip freeze
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually ChatGPT helped me solve this problem.
**Step 1:** install GDAL by:

```
!pip install gdal
```

**Step 2:** import `gdal` by this way rather than `import gdal`:

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

Hope it still can help someone who also meets this error.

Comment: Step 2 is all you need.